# Show that the eigenvalues of the cycle $C_n$ are $λ_j=2 \cos(\frac{2πj}{n})$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Show that the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix for cycle $C_n$ on $n$ vertices are $λ_j=2 \cos(\frac{2πj}{n})$.

I've seen a couple of references that just assume this to be true, but I have not found any sort of prove for it. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the matrix with columns $a_j = e_{j+1}$ for $j=1,\ldots,n-1$ and $a_n = e_1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B$ be the $n\times n$ matrix with columns $a_j = e_{j+1}$ for $j=1,\ldots,n-1$ and $a_n = e_1$, where $e_k$ is the $k$-th standard basis vector. Then the adjacency matrix of the $n$-cycle is $A = B+B^T$.

Now, $B$ is a unitary matrix and thus normal. So, it commutes with $B^T = B^*$. Hence, the eigenvalues of $A = B+B^*$ are given by $\{2\operatorname{Re}\lambda : \lambda\in\sigma(B)\}$, where $\sigma(B)$ is the set of eigenvalues of $B$.

Since $B$ is easily seen to have the eigenvalues $e^{\frac{2\pi ij}n}$, $j=0,\ldots,n-1$ (roots of unity), it follows that the eigenvalues of $A$ are
$$
2\operatorname{Re}e^{\frac{2\pi ij}n} = 2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi j}n\right).
$$

Comment: Appearently. ;-) Let $M$ be a normal matrix (i.e., $M^*M = MM^*$). If $Mx = 0$, then $\|M^*x\|^2 = (M^*x,M^*x) = (MM^*x,x) = (M^*Mx,x) = 0$, so also $M^*x=0$. Hence, $\ker M^* = \ker M$. Now, the matrix $B$ is normal. You can easily see that the same holds for $B-\lambda I$ for any $\lambda\in\mathbb C$. Thus, $\ker(B^*-\overline\lambda I) = \ker(B-\lambda I)$. So, if $x\in\ker(B-\lambda I)$, then $(B+B^*)x = Bx+B^*x = \lambda x+\overline\lambda x = (2\operatorname{Re}\lambda)x$.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Masie If you are content with my answer, please check it.